# Installing GRUB2 on Intel RAID1 volume fails to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, raid

I've come here as a kind of last resort, hopefully someone will be able to help me.
I work for a company which sells POS systems, recently we started using the HP RP5 5810 PC as the heart of our system.
All of our systems are configured with 2 disks in RAID1 for redundancy. This is accomplished by using the on-board Intel RAID controller.

Not so relevant but a little bit of background:
For production installs we use a simple master image with the OS on it, on which our software is installed later on.
However for in house testing/development, I maintained for several years now, a 'special' master image which will partition the disk of the system into 3 primary partitions, and one extended partition wither several other logical volumes inside it. Onto the 3 primary partitions, it is then possible to load our regular master image. On one of the extended logical volumes I have then installed GRUB4DOS with a custom made menu.lst file which allows the user to choose which of the primary 3 partitions he wants to boot.
This multi-boot master image has worked for several years across multiple systems we've used, however I can't for the life of me get it to work on this HP RP5 system.
GRUB4DOS simply fails to load for reasons unknown to me.

One interesting juicy detail: When booting from a USB stick (which also has GRUB4DOS installed), then going to the GRUB4DOS console, and then chainloading the MBR of the RAID1 volume, everything boots just fine.

As I said the above is not so relevant to this question, but it paints the picture of what I eventually want to accomplish.
I thought the problem could be attributed to GRUB4DOS's old infrastructure, and decided to try to switch to regular GRUB2, to see if this would resolve the problem. I have successfully managed to swap out GRUB4DOS with GRUB2 in my multi-boot master image, but am still getting the boot failures on this HP RP5 PC (it works on several other PC's).

Since I was quite new to custom installing GRUB2, I though I might have made a mistake, therefor I decided to install Ubuntu (14.10) on this PC, using the installer and leaving everything to default, indicating in the installer that I wanted to use the full disk for Ubuntu (erasing everything on it).
And to my surprise, that install also would not boot from my RAID1 array. So even the GRUB2 bootloader installed by the ubuntu installer is not booting up.
When I try to boot up my Ubuntu install, I just get a blinking cursor (my multi-boot attempts on the other hand would return an error in the sense of 'No boot disk found').

As I said, our regular master images, we have one for Windows POSReady 2009 (AKA Windows XP with extended support) and one for Windows 8, both work fine on this same system, booting up just fine when installing them.

On the datasheet of this system, SUSE Linux enterprise desktop is listed as officially certified, I tried installing an evaluation copy of this and to my surprise it is booting...

So how can I find out the difference between a SUSE installed GRUB2 and an Ubuntu installed GRUB2?